# Most optimal way of retrieving a property in Powershell

Tags: powershell

I'm just wondering, what is the optimal, fastest way of retrieving a property in powershell?

I'm using the (). right now to identify a remote computer's architecture (x86 or x64):

```
$arch = (Get-WmiObject –ComputerName XXXXX –Class Win32_OperatingSystem).osarchitecture
```

sometimes on a very very slow link, the command takes a while to resolve. For this reason, is there a faster way of retrieving a property than the (). method? I know there are different methods, for example:

```
... | Select-Object -expandproperty osarchitecture
```

Any suggestion as to which is better amongst all the possibilites? Thank you

Comment: No, there is not a "faster" way to retrieve a powershell object's property.  What is slow is your RPC connection to the PC.  As far as the most supported option? `Select-Object -ExpandProperty` since the `().` syntax doesn't work on collections before v3

Comment: Thanks for the info, what is the difference between the (). method and the select-object for example, do you know anything regarding this?

Comment: No difference unless you're working with a collection of objects in which case `().` is just short-hand for enumerating (only supported in v3+)

Comment: Your slowness is in retrieving the (rather small) object from the remote computer, not in extracting the data from it. You could try PSRemoting and running the code on the remote server (only sending that one value back), but it'd be a minimal gain. Get a faster connection to the remote machine.

Comment: Thank you for all the information!

Comment: In the background, `($col).Property` is pretty much doing `$col | ForEach-Object -MemberName Property` or alternatively `$col | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Property`

Comment: Interesting detail!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Comment from TheIncorrigible1 chosen as answer:

> No, there is not a "faster" way to retrieve a powershell object's
>   property. What is slow is your RPC connection to the PC. As far as the
>   most supported option? Select-Object -ExpandProperty since the ().
>   syntax doesn't work on collections before v3 – TheIncorrigible1